# Como añadir una función con onclick para muchos elementos, si el nombre de dicha función corresponde al ID del elemento pulsado en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo en un archivo varias funciones de JavaScript con su respectivo nombre, en otro archivo añado a distintos botones funciones sencillas como mostrar su ID con `elemento.onclick = function () { }`.

Lo que deseo hacer es añadir otra función la cual tiene el mismo nombre que el ID del elemento, ya pude obtener el ID, pero no sé cómo declarar el  `onfunction () { id() }` pues JavaScript piensa que `id` es el nombre de la función y no la variable ID que tiene el ID del elemento pulsado.

Quisiera algo como así (en "pseudocódigo"):

```
<boton id= "sumar"> 
boton.onclick = function () { ID() }
```

y éste al pulsarse llame a `sumar()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres es que cuando se pulse en un elemento se llame a una función que tendrá el mismo nombre que el ID del elemento llamado. Se me ocurren al menos dos métodos para realizar esto en JavaScript:

**Método 1: Usando la referencia a la función en `window`**

La idea es que todas las funciones disponibles en la ventana se pueden acceder haciendo `window["nombre de la función"]` (añadiendo `()` detrás para que se ejecute). Entonces en tu caso particular, lo que harías es que tendrías el ID del elemento en una variable, digamos `id` y lo que harías sería `window[id]()` para que se ejecute la función con el mismo nombre que el id del elemento.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function suma() {
  console.log("Función suma");
}

function resta() {
  console.log("Función resta");
}

function multiplicacion() {
  console.log("Función multiplicación");
}

function division() {
  console.log("Función división");
}

var botones = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var x = 0; x < botones.length; x++) {
  botones[x].onclick = function() {
    window[this.id]();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="suma">Suma</button>
<button id="resta">Resta</button>
<button id="multiplicacion">Multiplicación</button>
<button id="division">División</button>
```

**Método 2: Usando `eval`**

Sé que dicen que el `eval` es malvado (*evil*) y que se recomienda no usarlo (y voy a darles la razón en el 99% de los casos)... y eso es por lo que me quedaría con el primer método, pero no deja de ser una opción que funciona, así que te lo voy a poner de todos modos:

La idea es similar a lo de arriba, sólo que en lugar de acceder a la lista de funciones disponibles en la ventana, lo que vas a hacer es crear una cadena con el nombre de la función (el id) y añadirle `()` detrás.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function suma() {
  console.log("Función suma");
}

function resta() {
  console.log("Función resta");
}

function multiplicacion() {
  console.log("Función multiplicación");
}

function division() {
  console.log("Función división");
}

var botones = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var x = 0; x < botones.length; x++) {
  botones[x].onclick = function() {
    eval(this.id + "()");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="suma">Suma</button>
<button id="resta">Resta</button>
<button id="multiplicacion">Multiplicación</button>
<button id="division">División</button>
```

Comment: Así sera eval de malvado que le di Ejecutar al ejemplo y se abrió y cerro instantáneamente xD. Funciono justo lo que queria